# Dividing both sides of an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $|x+5|*|x-4|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ and $x$ are any real numbers, why can't I naively say $|x-4| < \frac{\epsilon}{|x+5|}$

Comment: You _can_ say that, unless $x=-5$.

Comment: You can, as long as you assume that $x\neq -5$. So you have to break the solution of your problem in two cases ($x$ equal or not to $-5$).

Comment: "why can't I naively say" who said you can't?  And under what circumstances.

Comment: You *can* say that.  But what are you going to say *after* that.  I suspect it is what you said *next* that you were told was wrong.  Not this.  I bet you the thing you said next was.  "Let $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{|x+5|}$".  And the thing you said after that was "therefore such a $\delta$ exists and we have proven ...".  ANd *that* is wrong because $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{|x+5|}$ is NOT a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't say $(x+5)*(x-4) < \epsilon \implies (x-4) < \frac {\epsilon}{x+5}$ because 1) That isn't true if $(x+5) < 0$.  and 2) It isn't true (or is defined) if $(x+5) = 0$.

You can do cases (if we absolutely have to).  If $x+5 > 0$ then $(x-4) < \frac {\epsilon}{x-5}$ and if $x+5 < 0$ then $(x-4) > \frac {\epsilon}{x-5}$.  Or $sign(x+5)(x-4) < \frac {\epsilon}{|x+5|}$ (assuming $x+5 \ne 0$).

However with absolute value signs we *know* everything is non-negative so the only thing we need to worry about is if $|x+5|=0$.

So if $|x+5|*|x-4| < \epsilon$ then:

1. if $x \ne 5$ (so $|x+5|\ne 0$) then $|x-4| < \frac {\epsilon}{|x+5|}$.  (That is acceptable and *not* naive.)
2. if $x = -5$ then ... well, we've concluded $x =-5$ and $|x-4| = 9$ and $0*9 = 0 < \epsilon$ so... well, that's that.

The question comes up though *who* told you you couldn't and what were you doing when you tried.

The usual times we use a variable $\epsilon$ and worry about absolute values being less than it, is when we are doing limits and maybe checking for continuity or taking derivatives or something of the sort.  In those cases:

Even though $x \ne -5$ and $|x+5||x-4| < \epsilon$ *does* imply $|x-4| < \frac {\epsilon}{|x+5|}$, that result, although true, will not *help* you.  If you try to assign, for instance, $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{|x-5|}$ and use that value of $\delta$ to prove whatever it is you had set out to prove, that will not work.  Because that $\delta$ is not a constant based entirely on constant $\epsilon$.  It is a function of varying different values based upon the values of the variable $x$.

I imagine *that* is why you were told you could not do it.

But that is not because it isn't true.  It *IS* true.  It is because the result you get will not be useful for doing what you want to do, and trying to use it to do what you want will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are inside a limit proof, in which case your RHS can't work as a $\delta$, which must be independent of $x$. See the other answers for more immediate mathematical problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because $x$ could be $-5$, in which case you would be dividing by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can, except when $x$ is $-5$.  When $x$ is $-5$, that would be a division by 0, which is undefined.

Comment: Sign error:  $|x + 5| = 0 \implies x = -5$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Thanks.